# Joining two tables to display count of rows in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I have two tables, `ngo_extra_data` and `ngo_foundation_data`. Following is the structure for the tables.

**ngo_extra_data**

```
id | ngo_name         | foundation_id
-----------------------------------------
1  | test ngo 1       | 1
2  | test ngo 2       | 1
3  | test ngo 3       | 2
4  | test ngo 4       | NULL
```

and

**ngo_foundation_data**

```
id | foundation_name  
----------------------
1  | foundation 1  
2  | foundation 2
3  | foundation 3
```

Now I want to display all the contents of **ngo_foundation_data** along with the number of *NGOs* having their `foundation_id` in **ngo_extra_data** as `id` in the foundation data table. So for example, 2 NGOs are registered under foundation with id `1` and 1 NGO is registered under foundation with id `2`. So the expected output would be

```
id | foundation_name  |  number_of_ngos
--------------------------------------------
1  | foundation 1     |  2
2  | foundation 2     |  1
3  | foundation 3     |  0
```

I tried to write the code in Magento like this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('ngodata/foundations')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(array('ngo' => 'ngo_extra_data'),'main_table.id = ngo.foundation_id',array('foundation_id'))
    ->columns('COUNT(*) AS total_ngos')
    ->group('foundation_id');
```

and it appears to work apart from an exception.

*When no ngo is registered under the foundation, it takes "null" as a foundation id as gives an incorrect result*.

If you could give me the SQL code for the same, I could convert it to the corresponding Magento code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join` and a `group by` so that you get a 0 result for the id's that aren't in ngo_extra_data table.

```
select nfd.id,nfd.foundation_name,count(ned.foundation_id) cnt
from ngo_foundation_data nfd
left join ngo_extra_data ned on nfd.id=ned.foundation_id
group by nfd.id,nfd.foundation_name
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. Now would you happen to know the corresponding magento code for it? :P

Comment: i'm sorry..i don't know.

Comment: It's not a problem. I could do that given some time. Thanks a lot again